# notched Geometry after Boolean

Tags: modeling

I am having quite a lot of trouble while modeling a tablet. Objects seem to be notched in after applying a boolean modifier and editing. The metal part of the tablet is slanted in. It happened after I applied the boolean modifier. Here are some examples:

**Rendered example**

[image: Indented? slanted? ERHH!! I have terrible english...]

**Material mode example**

[image: Unrendered example]

It is super weird... I really need help.

---

### Specs and tried solutions

- I am using Blender v2.79
- I am using cycles render
- I tried flipping normals

---

### Extra screenshots and Blender file.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image]

Comment: Why use booleans when you can create proper geometry? Booleans will almost always create n-gons and all kinds of topology problems. My unwanted advise would be to try and model this with quads.

Comment: Yep, you won't go far with boolean based modelling, use [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com) instead

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Can you explain that as an answer? I think it would be good for people like me to know that.

Comment: This has been aswered countless times, you only have to search this site for "boolean" to find all sorts of issues and problems that arise from using booleans

Comment: Could you post a screenshot in wireframe mode, so we can see what the geometry looks like? (I'm not a topology nazi. :))